# 3D plane fitting using Scipy least squares producing completely wrong fit

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I have a extracted the coordinates of a set of nodes from a mesh surface and put them in an array as such:

```
[[-2.5      4.       0.     ]
 [-6.5      0.       0.     ]
 [-6.5      0.      20.     ]
 ...
 [-3.5      3.      10.5    ]
 [-3.16667  3.33333 10.5    ]
 [-2.83333  3.66667 10.5    ]]
```

The points in this dataset comes from a flat surface from which I want to obtain an equation. I based my python code on the code from this [gist](https://gist.github.com/amroamroamro/1db8d69b4b65e8bc66a6). I was plotting the face again to verify if the calculated plane is correct/

The code I have is the following (where data is the array shown above):

```
def least_sq(self, data, order=1):

        # regular grid covering the domain of the data
        X,Y = np.meshgrid(np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5), np.arange(-3.0, 3.0, 0.5))
        XX = X.flatten()
        YY = Y.flatten()

        #1: linear, 2: quadratic
        if order == 1:
            # best-fit linear plane
            A = np.c_[data[:,0], data[:,1], np.ones(data.shape[0])]
            C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])    # coefficients
            print(C)
            # evaluate it on grid
            #Z = C[0]*X + C[1]*Y + C[2]

            #or expressed using matrix/vector product
            Z = np.dot(np.c_[XX, YY, np.ones(XX.shape)], C).reshape(X.shape)

        elif order == 2:
            # best-fit quadratic curve
            A = np.c_[np.ones(data.shape[0]), data[:,:2], np.prod(data[:,:2], axis=1), data[:,:2]**2]
            C,_,_,_ = scipy.linalg.lstsq(A, data[:,2])
            print(C)
            # evaluate it on a grid
            Z = np.dot(np.c_[np.ones(XX.shape), XX, YY, XX*YY, XX**2, YY**2], C).reshape(X.shape)

        # plot points and fitted surface
        fig = plt.figure()
        ax = fig.gca(projection='3d')
        ax.plot_surface(X, Y, Z, rstride=1, cstride=1, alpha=0.8)
        ax.scatter(data[:,0], data[:,1], data[:,2], c='r', s=50)
        plt.xlabel('X')
        plt.ylabel('Y')
        ax.set_zlabel('Z')
        ax.axis('equal')
        ax.axis('tight')
        plt.show()
```

The only thing I changed is the data provided. However the results are not correct as you can see here:

[image: IMG1]
[image: IMG2]

Answer (score 0):

for a flat plane/ lineair:  put in your code "*order = 1*" 
                      before the if line

*Z = C[0]*X + C[1]*Y + C[2]*   uncommented!
*#Z = np.dot(np.c_[XX, YY, np.ones(XX.shape)], C).reshape(X.shape)*

for a quadrat plane: *order = 2*

btw: the plane you have used for fitting makes me think of the situations of Anscombe quartet.